# Magento running out of memory

Tags: magento-1.8, memory

Every time I am getting the following message:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 81 bytes) in /public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line
>   270

However, I already have php_value **memory_limit** `2048M` in my `.htaccess` .which is kinda ridiculous.

Is there a way to see why its using loads of memory?

Comment: Does it happen on every page ? Or only one some specific pages ?

Comment: Every page, if I logout though the site is working fine

Comment: What if you switch back to the native Magento default/default theme ? Does this keep happening ?

Comment: Also, check if you have any extensions that are only doing anything when you're logged in to the frontend, since it seems that the issue occurs only when you're logged in.

Comment: Yes it happens when using the default theme

Comment: Have you checked with your hosting company to make sure they haven't set a hard limit of 268mb on their side? Is 268mb the memory_limit value in phpinfo()?

Answer (score 2):

To see current memory limit you can use php function `phpinfo()`

I assume setting memory limit with .htaccess file is not supported at the sever, so you can try other options:

1) In the file index.php add line

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

2) For the cgi/fastcgi run mode you can try to add file `.user.ini` as follows:

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```

After this please re-start web server or manually remove already running process.

3) If you have access to the `php.ini` file, then you can adjust the `memory_limit` value in this file also.

If all options do not work, please call you hosting provider support team :)

Comment: does the problem solved